# Django: overriding insert, update, delete in a model

Tags: python, django, django-models

Sometimes you want to do something when there is an event for model (on create object, on update object, on delete object).

There is a method you can override in `Model` called `save`. And it even has a parameter `forced_insert` which I first thought would always be set to a proper value meaning whether an object will be created or updated. But the parameter is optional and you cannot expect it to be right.

Searching in source code of `Model` led me to methods `_do_update` and `_do_insert`, but the underscore at the beginning tells me that this method is not recommended for use. And it also have a lot of parameters which pollute code when you override it.

The only solution left that I could find is using `django.db.models.signals`. But I believe they are meant to be used for external purposes like when you want to create a `UserProfile` on every `User` create. But I have some internal purposes like updating fields on update. Also using signals makes code look spreaded and harder to understand.

What would be the right way deal with implementing functional on these `Model` events?

Comment: I think that your best option (taking into the account things you mentioned which matter to you) is to override the `save` method on the `Model` using the `pk` field to check whether you're doing an update or a create, and use signals to handle the delete event.

Answer (score 1):

Look at this simplified condition from django base [`Model` `_save_table`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/db/models/base.py) method - decision to update or insert depends on model pk and force_insert value:

```
   def _save_table(self, raw=False, cls=None, force_insert=False,
                    force_update=False, using=None, update_fields=None):
        updated = False
        # ...
        if pk_set and not force_insert:
            updated = self._do_update()
        if not updated:
            result = self._do_insert()
        # ...
        return updated
```

And you can go that same way in your overrided save method if you want entirely custom update/insert operations:

```
def save(self, force_insert=False, **kwargs):
    updated = False
    if self.pk and not force_insert:
        updated = self.custom_update()
    if not updated:
        self.custom_insert()
    return updated
```

Comment: Thanks for that solution which should also work, but it also has some unwanted code which pollutes code.